# How can I get a list of DirectoryInfo where the name of the directories contains a string stored in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, string, list, linq, directory

Suppose I have a list of strings. These strings will be a part of the directory name that I want to open.

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>(){"Foo", "Bar", "LocalHost", "SomeIPAddress"};
```

If this is my list, my directories might look like this:

- Foo_TodaysDate_ThisFileNameIsMostlyLongAndUnhelpful
- Bar_TodaysDate_ThisFileNameIsMostlyLongAndUnhelpful
- LocalHost_TodaysDate_ThisFileNameIsMostlyLongAndUnhelpful
- SomeIPAddress_TodaysDate_ThisFileNameIsMostlyLongAndUnhelpful

So I have the code here to load the directory info into a list:

```
m_jsonDirectories = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ProgramData\SCLDDB\ReportLogs\")
    .GetDirectories()
    .OrderByDescending(p_f => p_f.LastWriteTime)
    .ToList();
```

Right now, I can load all the directories in the master directory into my variable, but I want to add something like:

```
 .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(/*A string found in my List above*/)
```

Edit: in the above statement, the parameter x is of type DirectoryInfo. So x.Name should return the Name of the Directory.

I don't know how to search

```
List.Any(s => string.Contains(s))
```

when I don't have a string variable already set. And ideally I'd just want to search each element of my list for a match without individually setting some temporary string variable.

Comment: `.Where(x => listOfStrings.Any(s => x.Name.Contains(s)));`

Comment: This doesn't work because the parameter s is type Directory Info.

Comment: No, it's not. `s` is of type `string`.

Comment: I mean, I totally agree that it should be, but I copied the code and when I hover the mouse over it, both x and s are type Directory Info. I'm really not sure why here.

Comment: That's impossible if you really have `var listOfStrings = new List<string>(){"Foo", "Bar", "LocalHost", "SomeIPAddress"};` like you've shown in your question.

Comment: '.Where(p_x => m_jsonDirectories.Any(p_s => p_x.Name.Contains(p_s)))' is the exact code I'm using. And both 'p_x' and 'p_s' are type DirectoryInfo.

Comment: DirectoryInfo.ToString(); maybe?

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot. Need coffee. You're totally right. I used the wrong variable. I need sleep. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It should be `m_jsonDirectories.Where(x => listOfStrings.Any(s => x.Name.Contains(s)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Where(x=> listOfStrings.Any(c=> x.Contains(c)))` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a sequence of `DirectoryInfos`, and a sequence of `strings`.

You want to filter the sequence of `DirectoryInfos` in such a way that only those `DirectoryInfos` that have a `Name` that starts with at least one of the strings that is in your sequence of strings.

So if your sequence of strings contains "Foo", than your end result should at least contain all `DirectoryInfos` whose `Name` start with `Foo`.

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> directoryInfos = ...

var result = directoryInfos
    .Where(directoryInfo => strings
           .Any(str => directoryInfo.Name.StartsWitch(str));
```

In words:

From the sequence of all DirectoryInfos, keep only those DirectoryInfos, of which the name of this DirectoryInfo starts with at Any of the strings in the sequence of strings.